# Famous recent paper on monetary Unions

Tags: currency, theory, empirical-evidence, european-union, optimal-currency-area

do you know any (theoretical or empirical) recent famous paper about monetary unions ? I heard that topics like "monetary unions at ZLB" or "fiscal coordination during crisis time" are quite popular these days.

Comment: Not sure whether “famous” is the word to use. If it were famous, you would already know about it. If you want a recent paper, there are various search engines. (I use Google Scholar, but I’m only a casual user.)

Comment: How do you define ‘famous paper’?  Also what do you consider ‘recent’? ZLB has been subject of research interest for almost half of a century.

Comment: Famous= with a lot of citation

Comment: No I'm not aware of all papers even if they are famous

Comment: I know Google Scholar. You are not helping me at all.

Comment: ZLB is mostly a research topic nowadays.

Comment: @user28453 "Famous= with a lot of citation" that just pushes the issue further. What is a lot of citations?  10, 100, 1000 or 10000? "ZLB is mostly a research topic nowadays" - no actually ZLB was a topic of intense research interest after the Japanese experience in 90s,

Answer (score 2):

Get a copy of De Grauwe's ["Economics of Monetary Union"](https://global.oup.com/ukhe/product/economics-of-monetary-union-9780198849544?cc=de&lang=en&). The most recent version (13th edition) is quite recent, from this year. So if there is a "famous" recent paper, it is discussed in there. The book is certainly more guided than searching for recent papers that cite Robert Mundell.

Answer (score -2):

My original answer did not point to a recent "famous" paper so this is an edit. One recent paper that looks interesting, but probably is not "famous", relates to the subject of rollover risk in a currency region. The title is "Coordination and Crisis in Monetary Unions". This can be discovered via keyword search. I do not know how one would find recent "famous" papers except to keyword search the most popular and highly respected economic journals.